# InvalidOperationException while reading Excel file with NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I have simple piece of code

```
public JsonResult ParseExcel(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var uploadedFileContent = file.InputStream;
    if (POIXMLDocument.HasOOXMLHeader(uploadedFileContent))
    {
        //xlsx
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(uploadedFileContent);
        var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
    }
return new JsonResult{};
}
```

So then I try to create a workbook using NPOI with uploaded Excel file, I get error: *Exception details:
Message: The hyperlink for cell G33 references relation rId5, but that didn't exist!*

I found out that this happens because G33 cell has a hyperlink, which is like this: *xxx@yyy.com'*. It has a single quote in the end. If I remove single quote, everything works as expected. Is there any other way to solve this problem rather that editing Excel file and removing single quote?

I tried using *WorkbookFactory.Create* and specifying second param as *ImportOption.TextOnly*. I tried creating *OPCPackage* object first and then passing it as a param. However, I get the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As passed file to `XSSFWorkbook` constructor, corrupts the whole thing, I did not find any other solution then to switch to a different library.